# Is this prior product similar to Patent us7462770?

Tags: prior-art-request, us7462770

I know about a product that holds this patent, but I also know that there's some prior art that seem to go against it:

http://www.vintagedrum.com/museum/images/duw000s.jpg
http://www.vintagedrum.com/museum/museum_snares03.htm
http://www.ctpropercussion.com/image/data/DSC01323.JPG
https://www.ctpropercussion.com/index.php?route=product/category&path=17_22

This kind of reinforced hoop is already seen in products from 1910, that had a regular distribution and are even in a museum, and still sold now as vintage products.
In these old model a metal guard was placed over the wooden hoop of the drum to protect it, basically with one of the designs used to define this patent.

Can you give an opinion about it?

The patent I'm referring to:
https://www.google.com/patents/US7462770